# HttpContext.User.Identity.Name not NULL only in debug mode (NULL from IIS or locally)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-express

I have a MVC project, and I'm using IHttpContextAccessor in order to use HttpContext in my controller.

```
public RequestController(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
{
  _contextAccessor = accessor;
}
```

I use another function in order to find out the name of the user that in the website.
So, I create a HTTP request, and then I get the user name in that way:
`_contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`

In debug mode everything look fine and when I'm routing to: localhost/user I get my user name, but when it's not debug mode and it's locally or from IIS it just return NULL. 
Anyone have an idea why?

Comment: What exactly is the authentication method you set on IIS/IIS Express and ASP.NET Core? Different settings do lead to different results. Learn what are the configuration files involved and edit the question to include critical lines from those files.

Comment: Thabnks. Finally I understood that I need to disable anonymous authentication from the server in IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I understood that I need to disable anonymous authentication from the server in IIS.

[Authentication in the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFQNW.png)

[Change to disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yRWp.png)